# magento - backslash in string

Tags: php, magento

I have a query -

```
$subscribedCats = stripslashes(implode(",", $subscribedCats1));  // '4','6'
$bulletin1 = Mage::getModel('bulletin/bulletinboard')->getCollection()
                                  ->addFieldToFilter('company_details_id', array('eq' =>$companyId))
                                  ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array('eq' =>1))
                                  ->addFieldToFilter(array('company_bulletin_category_id'),
                                    array(
                                        array(
                                            array('in' => array($subscribedCats)
                                        )
                                    )
                                ));
```

where "`$subscribedCats1`" getting the dynamic values. e.g. 4 & 6.
The above query generates the -

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `bulletin_board` AS `main_table` WHERE (company_details_id = '51') AND (is_active = 1) AND ((((company_bulletin_category_id IN('\'4\',\'6\'')))))
```

The result getting from the query is blank because of the backslash. Magento generates the backslash in `IN` condition. I tried using the `stripslashes` function, but not working. How should I remove the backslash ?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming there are no actual '' around 4 and 6...

Make sure that $subscribedCats = array.

Try this:

```
$subscribedCats = array(4, 6);

->addFieldToFilter(
'company_bulletin_category_id', array('in' => array($subscribedCats))
)
```